# Singular route helper to plural when adding Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using `link_to` in rails that requires  singular route helpers, which I obtained by writing in my `routes.rb` file:

`resources :contact_informations` which generates `new_contact_information` as a route helper and so on.

However when I add a `collection` under resources such as:

```
collection do
  get :a_new_route
end
```

the new generated route becomes plural like so:

`a_new_route_contact_informations`

How can I add more routes in a `collection` without it becoming plural?

Thanks!

Comment: You want `resources :contact_informations`, not `resource :contact_informations`.. Are you sure ? With `resources` it will be always _plural_.

Comment: Well all I know is that if I write `resources :contact_informations` it gives me `new_contact_information` in `rake routes`

Answer (score -3):

Use `member` instead of `collection`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: But `member` requires an `:id` doesn't it? And I have no `:id` to supply for these routes

Comment: Try it and see. Edit `routes.rb` then run `rake routes` to see the output.

Comment: Andy Waite, the route that your suggestion creates is of the format "collection/:id/action" which isn't what was asked.